# CodeIgniter escaping query with ActiveRecord.. don't want it to

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, escaping

I have this code:

```
$f->like("items", "<id>###</id>", "both");
```

When I `print_r` the database/query object, it just shows `%###%` and completely removes the `IDs`.  Is there any way to fix this?

I've tried escaping the `<` and `>` with `\` and but to no avail.

Comment: Also interested in seeing the response to this. +1ed.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't actually a problem in the first place.  I was looking at the print_r output in the browser window and only saw '%###%', but, upon viewing the source the   was still there.  It just wasn't showing because they were being interpreted as HTML tags.  Silly.

Comment: I tried echoing the parameter from within the method `like` and could only see` ### ` and so was beginning to wonder if some magic was going on. :)